# Client side sorting in datatable with serverside = true

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using bServerside = true in the datatable to get data from the server, but I would like to do client side sorting on the data that I have got initially. My client side sorting is not working. If I use bServerside = false, it won't load data from the server.

Comment: add some code. give more explanation.

Answer (score 8):

As the datable documentation points out:

> DataTables has two fundamental modes of operation:
>
> Client-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed in the web-browser.
> Server-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server.

http://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide

When you get the data from the server normally you only get the portion of data that is currently displayed. When you sort, you must sort the over the complete data and therefore new data from the server.